# Selenium WebDriver GetPageSource().Contains("")

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

What is the full meaning of below piece of code? I mean, which object implementing which class and using which method?

```
driver.getPageSource().contains("Text to find");
```

Answer (score 6):

Lets go one by one:

`driver.getPageSource()`

Here `driver` is an object ob WebDriver class  .  `getPageSource()` is method of WebDriver class.

So  `driver.getPageSource()` returns source code of the page which stored as string.  `contains` is method of a String class to check if a string contains in another string.

So, `driver.getPageSource().contains("Text to find");` will  return True if 'Text to find' is found in page source code else False.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

From the doc [Class RemoteWebDriver](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebDriver.html#getPageSource--)

> Get the source of the last loaded page. If the page has been modified
>   after loading (for example, by Javascript) there is no guarantee that
>   the returned text is that of the modified page.
>
> The page source returned is a representation of the underlying DOM:
>   do not expect it to be formatted or escaped in the same way as the
>   response sent from the web server. Think of it as an artist's
>   impression

getPageSource() --> return the source of the current page .

Contains()--> we check that word presents in that page or not

Answer (score 1):

The mentioned code is equivalent of -

```
String pageSource = driver.getPageSource();   //after loading some url through driver.get()
boolean result = pageSource.contains("Text to find");
```

Here, `driver` is your `WebDriver` object from which you call `getPageSource()` ([javadoc](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebDriver.html#getPageSource--)) method which returns a `String` object containing the source code of the loaded website.

Now on that returned `String` object, you are calling `contains()` method which checks whether the `String` includes(or contains) the text you passed in the argument.